# Editing the command line within a shell within vim

Tags: shell, vim

There's some clunky behavior I'd like to resolve:

In vim I can use `:terminal` to bring up a shell window. But if I type something into it, I can't edit it like a normal shell: I'm stuck either in a useless normal mode, or I'm in an insert mode where I can only write new letters or delete them at the end of the line. I can't move the cursor to the middle and change, say,

```
cd ~/Picturs/MyLovelyHusbandAndChildren2017/VacationPhotos/Aruba
```

into

```
cd ~/Pictures/MyLovelyHusbandAndChildren2017/VacationPhotos/Aruba
```

without simply deleting everything from `~/Pictur` to the end and rewriting it. Is there any way at all around this or is it a basic limitation of how vim works? This is frustrating to me because I'd like to use `ghci` in the shell window but this makes it much less responsive.

Comment: Can't reproduce on vim 8.1

Comment: I don’t have this problem: I can use both the arrow keys and my normal keyboard shortcuts for my shell (I have `set -o vi`).

Answer (score 0):

There are some specific configs you can do both on vim or neovim to tacle this issue, in my case, neovim, I have these lines on my init file:

```
augroup neovim_terminal
    autocmd!
    " Enter Terminal-mode (insert) automatically
    autocmd TermOpen * startinsert
    " Disables number lines on terminal buffers
    autocmd TermOpen * :set nonumber norelativenumber
    " allows you to use Ctrl-c on terminal window
    autocmd TermOpen * nnoremap <buffer> <C-c> i<C-c>
augroup END
```

Note the `autocmd TermOpen * startinsert`, that line makes sure, as soon as I enter a new terminal on neovim it will be in inert mode.